# SICP - Imperative versus Functional implementation of factorial

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, racket, sicp, imperative-programming

I am studying the SICP book with Racket and Dr. Racket. I am also watching the lectures on:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/5a-assignment-state-and-side-effects/

At chapter 3, the authors present the concept of imperative programming.

Trying to illustrate the meaning, they contrast an implementation of a factorial procedure using functional programming and to one which used imperative programming.

Bellow you have a recursive definition of an iterative procedure using functional programming:

```
(define (factorial-iter n)
  (define (iter n accu)
    (if (= n 0)
        accu
        (iter (- n 1) (* accu n))))
  ; (trace iter)
  (iter n 1))
```

Before the professor was going to present an imperative implementation, I tried myself.

I reached this code using the command "set!":

```
(define (factorial-imp n count product)
  (set! product 1)
  (set! count 1)
  (define (iter count product)
    (if (> count n)
        product
        (iter (add1 count) (* product count))))
  (iter count product))
```

However, the professor's implementation is quite different of my imperative implementation:

```
(define (factorial-imp-sicp n)
  (let ((count 1) (i 1))
    (define (loop)
      (cond ((> count n) i)
            (else (set! i (* count i))
                  (set! count (add1 count))
                  (loop))))
    (loop)))
```

Both codes, my implementation and the professor's code, reach the same results. But I am not sure if they have the same nature.

Hence, I started to ask myself: was my implementation really imperative? Just using "set!" guaranties that?

I still use parameters in my auxiliary iterative procedure while the professor's auxiliary iterative function does not have any argument at all. Is this the core thing to answer my question?

Thanks! SO users have been helping me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is splendidly mad, because it looks imperative, but it really isn't.  (Some of what follows is Racket-specific, but not in any way that matters.)

Starting with your implementation:

```
(define (factorial-imp n count product)
  (set! product 1)
  (set! count 1)
  (define (iter count product)
    (if (> count n)
        product
        (iter (add1 count) (* product count))))
  (iter count product))
```

Well, the only reason for the `count` and `product` arguments is to create bindings for those variables: the values of the arguments are never used.  So let's do that explicitly with `let`, and I will bind them initially to an undefined object so it's clear the binding is never used (I have also renamed the arguments to the inner function so it is clear that these are different bindings):

```
(require racket/undefined)

(define (factorial-imp n)
  (let ([product undefined]
        [count undefined])
    (set! product 1)
    (set! count 1)
    (define (iter c p)
      (if (> c n)
          p
          (iter (add1 c) (* p c))))
    (iter count product)))
```

OK, well, now it is obvious that any expression of the form `(let ([x <y>]) (set! x <z>) ...)` can immediately be replaced by `(let ([x <z>]) ...)` so long as whatever `<y>` is has no side effects and terminates.  That is the case here, so we can rewrite the above as follows:

```
(define (factorial-imp n)
  (let ([product 1]
        [count 1])
    (define (iter c p)
      (if (> c n)
          p
          (iter (add1 c) (* p c))))
    (iter count product)))
```

OK, so now we have something of the form `(let ([x <y>]) (f x))`: this can be trivially be replaced by `(f <y>)`:

```
(define (factorial-imp n)
  (define (iter c p)
    (if (> c n)
        p
        (iter (add1 c) (* p c))))
  (iter 1 1))
```

And now it is quite clear that your implementation is not, in fact, imperative in any useful way.  It does mutate bindings, but it does so only once, and never uses the original binding before the mutation.  This is essentially something which compiler writers call 'static single assignment' I think: each variable is assigned once and not used before it is assigned to.

---

PS: 'splendidly mad' was not meant as an insult, I hope it was not taken as such, I enjoyed answering this!

Comment: I was in doubt about how to interpret this comment... Since you did not up vote the question, I thought it was an insult. But thanks, no problem. Great answer! =)

Comment: @fallowzito Sorry, bad at remembering to vote, I have now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `set!` introduces side effects by changing a binding, however you change it from the passed value to `1` without using the passed value and you never change the value afterwards one might look at it as if `1` and `1` were constants passed to the helper like this:

```
(define (factorial-imp n ignored-1 ignored-2)
  (define (iter count product)
    (if (> count n)
        product
        (iter (add1 count) (* product count))))
  (iter 1 1))
```

The helper updates it's `count` and `product` by recursing and thus is 100% functional.

If you were to do the same in an imperative language you would have made a variable outside a loop that you would update at each step in a loop, just like the professors implementation.

In your version you have altered the contract. The user needs to pass two arguments that are not used for anything. I've illustrated that by calling them `ignored-1` and `ignored-2`.